# How to have update notification for both distro and flatpak updates?

Tags: updates, 22.04

EDIT: I realize from the comment that my question was very unclear, so let me rephrase.

As system default i only get distro updates notification, i would like to include the flatpak ones.

I seem to understand that on fedora this is accomplished by gnome-software (i may be wrong). for this reason i think about managing notification by gnome-software and not update-manager.

Anyway, however implemented i would like a daily notification of available updates both from distro and flatpaks.

Is it doable?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Have you tried using `flatpak-update`  (eg. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/flatpak-update.1.html)   Note:  I don't use *flatpaks* thus have no experience *living with them* as a user.

Comment: my goal is to have system and flatpak update notification all togheter, i know i can update flatpack from cli. i would like the auto update notification to work system wide (flatpak, snaps and apt) i know gnome-software can do this. But ubuntu default is to just auto-update apt and snaps. i would like to change this default

Comment: "*I tried to uninstall update-manager but i never seem to get auto-updates*" Correct, because you specifically wanted "*upgrades to be managed by gnome-software*" which lacks auto-upgrade capability.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*auto update notification*." Automatic updates (unattended-upgrades) have no notification at all. Perhaps you mean the upgrade prompt dialog provided by update-manager which appears at regular intervals?

Comment: I want the system to notify me updates both from distro and from flatpaks, exactly like fedora does. Is it possible to do it?